# $A$ and $B$ are everywhere dense in metric space $M$. Can $A$ ∩ $B$ = ∅?

Tags: general-topology

$A$ and $B$ are everywhere dense in metric space $M$. Is it possible $A$ ∩ $B$ = ∅?

If I understand correctly:

1. ∅ is nowhere dense
2. If $A$ and $B$ are open then $A$ ∩ $B$ is dense
3. If $A$ is open and $B$ is closed then $A$ ∩ $B$ is dense
4. If $A$ and $B$ are both closed then $A$ ∩ $B$ *can* be dense

Is word *everywhere* change something here? Should I choose two closed sets to prove what $A$ ∩ $B$ = ∅? Which?

Comment: What is meant by "everywhere dense"? Does it mean the complement of a nowhere dense set?

Comment: @amsmath "everywhere dense" is just an old-fashioned word for "dense". It contrasts with "nowhere dense".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $M := \mathbb{R}$. The rationals and irrational numbers are dense but disjoint.

Comment: Are these sets "everywhere dense"?

Comment: @amsmath When googling the term I found that it is used by some authors for what we use my regard as dense, see i.e [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Dense_set)

Comment: Oh, I see. Why this terminology with "everywhere" then? It's superfluous.

Comment: Or [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Everywhere_Dense). Neither the wiki page of "Dense set" or "nowhere dense set" contain any mentions of "everywhere dense".

Comment: @amsmath It seems to be superfluous, but I'm no expert.

Answer (score 1):

1. is correct. 2. is too, but can be generalised, see below.

3 and 4 are strange/trivial: a *closed* dense set must equal $X$. So 3 trivialises to 
if $A$ is open and dense and $B=X$ then $A \cap B$ is dense, and $A \cap B = A \cap X =A$ so that is true by assumption regardless of whether $A$ is open or not.
4. Just says that $X \cap X=X$ is dense in $X$, which is also trivial.

In fact if $A$ is open and dense and $B$ is only dense (not open) then $A \cap B$ is dense. And taking $A$ as the rationals and $B$ as the irrationals in $\Bbb R$ in the usual topology, we see it is possible to have disjoint dense sets when neither is open.